# Django - Serialize parents associations

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a serialized RESTful response from a One to N relationship.

I have a table Lexicon, primary key lexicon_id, I have another table lexicon_attributes, primary key lexicon_attribute_id, foreign key lexicon_id

```
class Lexicons(models.Model):
    """
    Holds all words
    """
    lexicon_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    word = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'lexicons'

class LexiconAttributes(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'lexicon_attributes'

    lexicon_attribute_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    lexicon_id = models.ForeignKey('Lexicons', db_column='lexicon_id', related_name="lexicon_attributes")
    is_verb = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    is_plural = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    is_past_tense = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
```

serializer

```
class LexiconAttributesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = LexiconAttributes 
       fields = '__all__'  

class LexiconsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lexicon_attributes = LexiconAttributesSerializer(source='*', many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Lexicons
```

When I make a request for /lexicons/2/

`{
    "lexicon_id": 2,
    "lexicon_attributes": {
        "lexicon_id": 2
    },
    "word": "computer",
    "date_created": "2015-07-30T20:29:19Z",
    "date_modified": "2015-07-30T20:29:19Z"
}`

How do I get the other fields in lexicon_attributes table

FYI I am week two into Django, my app was originally done in Cakephp3

Comment: Post your code that fetches your lexicon objects. Consider looking into Tastypie or Django REST Framework

Answer (score 1):

`class LexiconsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lexicon_attributes = LexiconAttributesSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Lexicons
        fields = '__all__'`

fixed the problem for me after 3 days